# Ubuntu and windows 10 dual boot GRUB shows windows recovery environment loader

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-10

I recently installed a fresh windows 10 OS. Once windows 10 was installed, I installed Ubuntu 14.04 for dual boot. Once I restart the system the grub menu shows Ubuntu and at the end of the list there is a 'Windows recovery environment loader (/dev/sda1)' .

I am unable to get an option for Windows 10.

When I select Windows recovery environment, it boots onto windows without any problems.

I would like to know if this can be solved. I would like to get windows 10 option on my grub.

I have already tried update-grub.

Here is the link to bootrepair summary: 
http://paste.ubuntu.com/13285386/

Output of fdisk -l

```
Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000a5b06

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048     1026047      512000    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2         1026048  1271128063   635051008    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3      1680728064  1953519615   136395776    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4      1271130110  1680728063   204798977    5  Extended
Partition 4 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sda5      1271130112  1290659839     9764864   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda6      1290661888  1680728063   195033088   83  Linux

Partition table entries are not in disk order

Disk /dev/sdc: 2063 MB, 2063597568 bytes
226 heads, 39 sectors/track, 457 cylinders, total 4030464 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000efe8f

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1   *        2048     4030463     2014208    b  W95 FAT32
```

Comment: Do you see the text-mode Windows boot menu (e.g. https://www.tenforums.com/attachments/tutorials/37308d1442150625-enable-disable-f8-advanced-boot-options-windows-10-a-f8_windows_boot_manager.png) after you choose Windows Recovery in GRUB? If not, perhaps this is the blurred screen? You can turn it off or reduce the timeout in the Windows System control panel -> Advanced tab -> Startup and Recovery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Windows Recovery Environment is just a misleading name**.

GRUB detects all boot loaders being installed on the machine.

The first Windows boot loader detected points to the **Win RE**.

When you select Windows Recovery Environment from GRUB -

**... the complete Windows Boot Environment will be started**.

Comment: I sure hope it's only a misleading name problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo os-prober
sudo update-grub
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Tried it. Still the same.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there's a better grub configuration for booting Windows 10 than the automatically generated one that starts the bootloader on the recovery partition, but as far as the name goes, "Windows Recovery Environment" comes straight from the the output of `os-prober`, which is mostly a stack of shell scripts.

For my old school BIOS/MBR configuration, the relevant probe is in `/usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/20microsoft`.

(I'm using Debian 8 "jessie" rather than Ubuntu; the file paths may not be correct for Ubuntu.)

As a compromise so `update-grub` will still be useful, I hand-edited the probe to say something generic:

```
elif grep -qs "W.i.n.d.o.w.s. .R.e.c.o.v.e.r.y. .E.n.v.i.r.o.n.m.e.n.t" "$2/$boot/$bcd"; then
        long="Windows (bootloader)"
```

and re-ran `sudo update-grub`.

Answer (score 0):

If it does boots, what is the problem?
If you are confused with the name of it, then rename it using something like grub-customizer.
If there is a problem (which I don't see), then try to fixboot & fixmbr using windows tools and then repair grub.

Comment: Yes. I know there is no problem. There are some minor problems. When I click on the windows recovery loader, for 15 seconds the screen gets blurred and then windows boots. I just wanted to make sure that nothing messes up in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I think your are facing a problem with dual booting with Windows 10,
I suggest you to make a live Ubuntu usb pendrive then in live Ubuntu open terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and type the below command.. (for repair the grub you must have INTERNET connection)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
boot-repair
```